# Handling ScrollEvent on TableView takes too much of the CPU Time

Tags: events, javafx, scroll, event-handling, tableview

I have a `TableView` named `tableVerre` and I want to have every row of it checked for a criteria ( `stock` column value ) and execute some code on them as I scroll so I wrote this code but it makes the program consume a lot of CPU time, I'm not familiar with Lambda expressions so is there a simpler way to write this ? :

```
tableVerre.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {

    stock.setCellFactory(column -> {

    return new TableCell<VerreFX, Number>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

            TableRow<VerreFX> currentRow = getTableRow();

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText("");
                setGraphic(null);
               currentRow.setStyle(tableVerre.getStyle());
            } else {
                setText(getItem().toString());
            }

            if (!isEmpty()) {
                if ((int) item == 0 && st.getVerresBOX()) currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightcoral");
            }
        }
    };
});

            }
     });
```

Comment: Why are you replacing the `cellFactory` in the scroll handler? Probably the cells are not even recreated unless you resize the table...

Comment: Where would I put it ? by the way the cells are recreated without resizing the table .

Comment: The cells will be recreated if you set a new cell factory (AFAIK). If you don't continually replace the cell factory, they will simply be reused (the `updateItem(...)` method will be called on existing cells) as the user scrolls. Obviously, simply calling `updateItem()` is far less performance intensive than repeatedly replacing all the cells.

Answer (score 2):

The table view will reuse cells as the user scrolls, and will automatically call `updateItem` on the cells when they are reused for new items. So you should set the cell factory only once, and then just let the table view take care of doing the job it is designed to do. You can set the cell factory in the `initialize()` method if you are using FXML, or just wherever you create the table and columns otherwise.

Your cell implementation isn't quite correct: because a cell may be reused to display any two different items arbitrarily, you need to account for all possible conditions. In your implementation, if a cell shows an item for which `item.intValue()==0` and is then reused to show an item for which `item.intValue() != 0`, then the style will not be updated correctly.

Also note that you should "convert" a `Number` to an `int` by calling `intValue()`.

```
TableColumn<VerreFX, Number> stock ;

// ...

stock.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<VerreFX, Number>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        TableRow<VerreFX> currentRow = getTableRow();

        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText("");
            setGraphic(null);
           currentRow.setStyle(tableVerre.getStyle());
        } else {
            setText(getItem().toString());
        }

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            if (item.intValue() == 0 && st.getVerresBOX()) {
                currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightcoral");
            } else {
                currentRow.setStyle(tableVerre.getStyle());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You should be able to remove the scroll event handler entirely.

Comment: Yes I'm using fxml and setting the cell factory in initialize() was exactly my approach but once a row changes style every cell that's displayed in that row will take the same style ! didn't update itself .

Comment: It is what you mentioned but I don't have that bug ! I used to , and I found a solution to it (updating cells on each scroll event) that consumes cpu timewhich is the code in the question , and I found a way to prevent that by updating the cells when the scrolling is finished. Thank you James

Answer (score 0):

Firstly beside over CPU time using you didn't cover all the scrolling situations because if the user scrolls using the key Down/Up or using the scroll bar the scroll event will not be fired. So you have to add two more `EventFilter`, the first will handle the Scrolling using the Scrollbar.

```
tableVerre.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,(
            MouseEvent event)->
    {
        if ((event.getTarget() instanceof TableColumnHeader) | event.isDragDetect()) {
            System.err.println("Mouse Draged : " + event.toString());

            stock.setCellFactory((TableColumn<VerreFX, Number> column) -> {

                return new TableCell<VerreFX, Number>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        TableRow<VerreFX> currentRow = getTableRow();

                        if (empty || item == null) {
                            setText("");
                            setGraphic(null);
                            currentRow.setStyle(tableVerre.getStyle());
                        } else {
                            setText(getItem().toString());
                        }

                        if (!isEmpty()) {
                            if ((int) item == 0 && st.getVerresBOX()) {
                                currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightcoral");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            });
        }
    });
```

And the second one will handle the scrolling using the keyboard Key DOWN/UP.

```
tableVerre.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN | event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
            stock.setCellFactory(column -> {

                return new TableCell<VerreFX, Number>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        TableRow<VerreFX> currentRow = getTableRow();

                        if (empty || item == null) {
                            setText("");
                            setGraphic(null);
                            currentRow.setStyle(tableVerre.getStyle());
                        } else {
                            setText(getItem().toString());
                        }

                        if (!isEmpty()) {
                            if ((int) item == 0 && st.getVerresBOX()) {
                                currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightcoral");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            });
        }
        System.err.println("Key Pressed : " + event.toString());
    }
});
```